# How to show this inverse map is continuous?

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]

My idea of proving is this:
If we can show this map actually maps the so called "boundary points", which are the points arbitrarily closed to the boundary, say, has distance /epsilon, to the boundary points.

And hence it would apply, as the boundary points and the points nearby would extent to the centre.
Would it work?

Answer (score 2):

Under these hypotheses, $\mathbb x^{-1}$ is not necessarily continuous.

For example, let $U=(-\pi,\pi)\times \mathbb R \subseteq \mathbb R^2$, let $\mathbb x\colon U\to \mathbb R^3$ be the map
$$
\mathbb x(u,v) = (\sin 2u, \sin u, v),
$$
and let $S\subset\mathbb R^3$ be the image of $\mathbb x$. Then $S$ is a "generalized cylinder" whose projection onto the $xy$-plane is a figure-8 curve (a ***leminscate***) that looks like this:

[image: Figure-8 curve]

We can take $V=\mathbb R^3$, and then $S\cap V=S$ and $\mathbb x\colon U\to S\cap V$ is a bijection. Moreover, $d\mathbb x|_{(u,v)}$ has rank $2$ for all $(u,v)\in U$. But $\mathbb x^{-1}$ is not continuous, because there is a sequence of points $(x_i,y_i,0)\in S$ that approaches $(0,0,0)$, but their inverse images have no convergent subsequence in $U$.

Comment: I have an idea on proving. But I dunno where went wrong.